# Value not being assigned

Tags: c

This is my little snippet that is giving me problems:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char string[75] = {0};
char *pChar;
int count = 0;

printf("String: ");
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);

printf("Numero parole: %d\n", countWords(string, strlen(string)));

// Suddivido la stringa nelle varie parole
pChar = strtok(string, " ");
while(pChar){
    if(isWord(pChar, strlen(pChar))){

        count += strlen(pChar);

    }
    pChar = strtok(NULL, " ");

}

printf("Lettere totali: %d\n", count);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

The problem is that no value is being assigned to count variable. I know there is something wrong but I still don't know what's wrong.

Thanks for helping ^^

*P.S. I'm currently learning C so this probably is a stupid question.*

*P.P.S. As requested here's the isWord function: (nevermind the comments they're in italian)*

```
// Controlla se è una parola
int isWord(char string[], int length){

int i = 0;                  // Contatore
int countAlpha = 0;         // Se il carattere è alfabetico. Non vengono
                            // contate le parole che contengono numeri

// Inizio scorrendo tutta la stringa tranne l'ultimo carattere che è un
// terminatore di stringa
for(i; i < length - 1; i++){

    // Se il carattere è alfabetico allora aumento il contatore isAlpha
    if(isalpha(string[i])){

        countAlpha++;

    // Altrimenti il carattere non è una lettera
    } else {

        countAlpha = 0;

    }

}

if(countAlpha == i){

    return 0;

} else {

    return 1;

}
```

}

Comment: Most likely isWord is never returning `true`.  Can we see isWord, as well as your input string?

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework tag.

Comment: My mistake, in the isWord function `for(i; i < length - 1; i++)` has to be `for(i; i < length; i++)`.
I'm a dumbass sorry :(

Comment: `if(countAlpha == i)` is returning the wrong values. You have them reversed for what you are trying. If `countAlpha == i`  should `return 1` (for true), while `else` should `return 0` (for false). As it is, the function is returning the inverse of what you want.

Comment: Sei il terzo italiano che trovo su StackOverflow ;)

Comment: @BlackBear Tu per me sei il primo. Comunque questo sito è una manna dal cielo per i programmatori. Inoltre è veramente ben fatto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `count` is not incrementing then it is because of one of the following:

a) `strlen(pChar);` returns 0

b) `if(isWord(pChar, strlen(pChar)))` is never true

c) `while(pChar)` is never valid

You can validate what is working and what is not by making use of your interactive debugger and stepping through your code, line by line, as it executes.

Based on your additional changes since this was first posted, it seems the trouble is in your `isWord` function. It seems that function is returning the opposite values that you meant. Change it so that the `if(countAlpha == i)` returns 1 (for true) and its `else` returns 0 (for false).

Answer (score 0):

fgets might store a new line character so isWord returns false because isalpha('\n') is false.

Answer (score 0):

little snippet could come with a a little code explanation :)

By the Way as pointed by others the issue is in the return value of the function `isWord` But more importantly why are you doing all that work ?

The function `isWord` is supposed to count if the word consist of all alphabets. if so return success code else failure code. Main function on success will increment count by `strlen` of the string.

But is this all necessary ?

Changes Suggested : Instead of return error code or success code and then do `strlen` make `isWord` return the total number of characters on success and `-1` on failure and increment `count` accordingly. This will save you on a `strlen` function call :)

This seems a lot better :) dont you agree ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isWord(char string[], int length){

int i = 0,countAlpha = 0;

for(; i < length - 1; i++){

    if(!isalpha(string[i])){

        countAlpha = -1;
        break;

    }else {

        countAlpha++;

    }

}

return countAlpha;

} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

char string[75] = {0};
char *pChar;
int ret = 0,count = 0;

printf("String: ");
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);

// Suddivido la stringa nelle varie parole
pChar = strtok(string, " ");

while(pChar){

    if( (ret=isWord(word, strlen(word))) != -1){

        count += ret;

    }

    pChar = strtok(NULL, " ");  

}

printf("Lettere totali: %d\n", count);

return 0;
}
```